# Why the focus doesn't work when i click on input (Vue)?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem, when I want to focus on some input, I must click twice, and I don't know how set cursor at the end of input. I tried with $refs, but something deeper is going on. Any suggestion?

HTML CODE

```
<div class="input-container">
  <h3 class="field-value" v-show="!showField('name')" @click="focusField('name')">{{ user.name }}</h3>
  <input v-model="user.name" v-show="showField('name')" id="user-name" type="text" ref="test" class="field-value form-control" @focus="focusField('name')" @blur="blurField">
</div>

<div class="input-container">
 <h3 class="field-value" v-show="!showField('email')" @click="focusField('email')">{{ user.email }}</h3>
 <textarea name="testing" id="editableTextArea" cols="30" rows="10" v-model="user.email" v-show="showField('email')" type="email" class="field-value form-control" @focus="focusField('email')" @blur="blurField"></textarea>
</div>
```

VUE CODE

```
data() {
    return {
        user: {
            name: pa.data.text1,
            email: pa.data.text2
        },
        editField: '',
    }
},
methods: {
    hi(){
        this.$refs.test.$el.focus();
        console.log(1);
    },
    focusField(name) {
        this.editField = name;
    },
    blurField() {
        this.editField = '';
    },
    showField(name) {
        return (this.user[name] == '' || this.editField == name)
    },
}
```

Comment: This design and way its implemented doesn't seems quite good. Focus Blur of input all are default behavior and it design to serve standard web accessibility without any manual intervention of code. If you are doing it, you need to be very careful, it could break things.

Comment: Coming to you problem, you are using v-show that basically mean items are not in **DOM** as of now, on click you are making it visible and at the same time you are calling focus function as well. Focus function is getting executed even before input is appears in DOM, that's why it's not working. And hiding current element as well, that loose focus once you hide it.

Comment: So, its like you are hiding and showing element and trying to focus in between. DOM is not quite render the element in between.

More over, I would suggest you to visit this approach again, most of accessibility use case handled by element itself by default. If you can share stackblitz that could be more helpful

Comment: I understood what did you say, but I do not have any ideas how to approach to this problem, here is link to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gkpqzk

Comment: @AbhinavKumar can you see my problem on stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah, I got that issue and added in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setTimeout to apply the focus, it's not recommended but you can use it, as you have some specific use case here.

Here is the change required

```
focusField(name) {
            this.editField = name;
            setTimeout(()=>{
              this.$refs[name].focus(); // access the ref and make it focus after a delay make sure element appear in the DOM
            },200);
            
        },
```

You also need to change some of the method bindings from input, like a blur, when you are moving to any other element blur will call automatically.

Also declare all the ref for inputs elements.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-m6zjww)

Comment: Thank you a lot, first I did like this, but I know that timeout is not good solution at all, so i use $this.nextTick like: 
this.$nextTick(() => {
                    this.$refs.test.focus();
                    this.$refs.test1.focus();
 }) 
and this works. Thank you a lot!!!